# Set "Other" Value at last of array in php without using looping

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have tried to set "Other" value at last of array without using any looping. The array looks like:

```
array
(
[15] => Business Copywriting & Press Releases
[11] => Business Plans
[20] => Languages
[17] => Legal Writing
[19] => **Other**
[10] => Presentation Design
[13] => Proof reading & Editing
[16] => RESEARCH & SUMMARIES
[12] => RESUMES & COVER LETTERS
[18] => Transcriptions
[14] => Translating
)
```

Comment: use `array_push()`... what did you try? show your code snippet...

Comment: I think what you mean is to order them?

Comment: these values comes from db so how i can use array_push keys are changeable but Other value name not changeable

Comment: I just want to set Other to last of array with it's key

Comment: how can we know your problem is if you didn't even include your php code

Comment: The key is changeable you can not fix 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i'm understand, you want to move `**Other**` to the end of an array.

Maybe this can help.

```
$key = array_search ('**Other**', $arr);
unset($arr[$key]); // remove **other**

array_push($arr, "**Others**"); // put **Other** in the end of array
```

but if you want to keep your array key, you cannot using `array_push()` but this will do;

```
$key = array_search ('**Other**', $arr);
unset($arr[$key]); // remove **other**

$arr[$key] = '**Other**';
```

Answer (score 0):

### Concate `**Other**` value (value of the array at index 19)

I don't understand your question. What I understood is that you want to concate the value of the array on the index 19 to the end of the array. If I am right, you may want to do so:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    15 => 'Business Copywriting & Press Releases',
    11 => 'Business Plans',
    20 => 'Languages',
    17 => 'Legal Writing',
    19 => '**Other**',
    10 => 'Presentation Design',
    13 => 'Proof reading & Editing',
    16 => 'RESEARCH & SUMMARIES',
    12 => 'RESUMES & COVER LETTERS',
    18 => 'Transcriptions',
    14 => 'Translating',
];

$arr[] = $arr[19];

var_dump($arr);

// array (size=12)
//   15 => string 'Business Copywriting & Press Releases' (length=37)
//   11 => string 'Business Plans' (length=14)
//   20 => string 'Languages' (length=9)
//   17 => string 'Legal Writing' (length=13)
//   19 => string '**Other**' (length=9)
//   10 => string 'Presentation Design' (length=19)
//   13 => string 'Proof reading & Editing' (length=23)
//   16 => string 'RESEARCH & SUMMARIES' (length=20)
//   12 => string 'RESUMES & COVER LETTERS' (length=23)
//   18 => string 'Transcriptions' (length=14)
//   14 => string 'Translating' (length=11)
//   21 => string '**Other**' (length=9)
```

### Concate `**Other**` after searching (variable indexes)

If the index is variable:

```
<?php

$arr = [...];

$key = array_search('**Other**', $arr);
$arr[] = $arr[$key];

var_dump($arr);

// array (size=12)
//   ...
//   21 => string '**Other**' (length=9)
```

You may want to remove `$arr[$key]` after concate:

```
<?php

$arr = [...];

$key = array_search('**Other**', $arr);
$arr[] = $arr[$key];
unset($arr[$key]);

var_dump($arr);

// array (size=11)
//   15 => string 'Business Copywriting & Press Releases' (length=37)
//   11 => string 'Business Plans' (length=14)
//   20 => string 'Languages' (length=9)
//   17 => string 'Legal Writing' (length=13)
//   10 => string 'Presentation Design' (length=19)
//   13 => string 'Proof reading & Editing' (length=23)
//   16 => string 'RESEARCH & SUMMARIES' (length=20)
//   12 => string 'RESUMES & COVER LETTERS' (length=23)
//   18 => string 'Transcriptions' (length=14)
//   14 => string 'Translating' (length=11)
//   21 => string '**Other**' (length=9)
```

> notice: the initial `**Other**` is no longer existing

### Concate string `Other`

Otherwise, if you want to concate the string `Other`:

```
<?php

$arr = [...];

$arr[] = 'Other';

var_dump($arr);

// array (size=12)
//   ...
//   21 => string 'Other' (length=5)
```

Comment: I have to get all values from this query after then i have get array which is i posted at top in this array i am getting Other value i want this array but the Other value is located at bottom of array
  $sub=$this->SubCategory->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('SubCategory.cat_id'=>16)));
  pr($sub);
  asort($sub);
  pr($sub);

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an array -

```
$array = array("one", "two", "three");
```

Now you want to add a new element i.e. **Others** in the array without using the loop, then you can use array_push function to achieve your desired output -

```
array_push($array, "others");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
$arr = [
    15 => 'Business Copywriting & Press Releases',
    11 => 'Business Plans',
    20 => 'Languages',
    17 => 'Legal Writing',
    19 => '**Other**',
    10 => 'Presentation Design',
    13 => 'Proof reading & Editing',
    16 => 'RESEARCH & SUMMARIES',
    12 => 'RESUMES & COVER LETTERS',
    18 => 'Transcriptions',
    14 => 'Translating',
];

$key = array_search('**Other**', $arr); // $key = 19;
unset($arr[$key]);
array_push($arr, "Other");

print_r($arr);
```